# Prove that $S$ is an upper bound of $C$ if and only if $x > S + \epsilon$ then $C \in x$

Tags: calculus

Let $C$ be a nonempty set of numbers, $S$ is a given real number.

Here's how far I've gotten:

First, let's assume that $S$ is an upper bound of $C$, then we can assume that there is an $x$ that belongs to $C$ so that $x > S + \epsilon$ (for every  $\epsilon>0$).

Since $S$ is an upper bound of $C$ we  can achieve the following:
$S+\epsilon>S>=x>S+\epsilon$
So we proved our assumption to be wrong, so if $X>S+\epsilon$ then $X$ does not belong to $C$.

Now from the other side I'm not sure how to get on with it, we need to prove that if $X > S + \epsilon$ and if $x$ does not belong to $C$, then $S$ is an upper bound, but I feel like I'm missing something.

Comment: Do you mean the above holds hold for every $\epsilon >0$? Otherwise it is not true.

Comment: Yeah sorry forgot to add that

Comment: Why would you write "$x>S+\varepsilon$ for all $\varepsilon>0$" rather than just "$x>S$"?

Answer (score 1):

The contrapositive of $x>S+\epsilon \implies x\notin C$ is $x\in C\implies x\leq S+\epsilon$. But if this holds for each $\epsilon >0$, then we necessarily have $x\leq S$ for each $x\in C$ so S must be an upper bound.